# ViewChild vs content child

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  styles: [
    'todo-app { margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px; }'
  ],
  template: "
    <content>
      <todo-app>
        <app-footer>
          <small>Yet another todo app!</small>
        </app-footer>
      </todo-app>
    </content>
  "
})  
export class AppComponent {}
****************
//todo-app-comp
{
    @Component(...)
    class TodoAppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
      @ContentChild(FooterComponent) footer: FooterComponent
      ngAfterContentInit() { this.footer now points to the instance of "FooterComponent"
      }
    }
}
```

`
In the snippet above we define two more components FooterComponent and AppComponent. FooterComponent visualizes all of the content passed between the opening and closing tags of its host element (content to be projected). On the other hand, AppComponent uses TodoAppComponent and passes FooterComponent between its opening and closing tags. So given our terminology from above, FooterComponent is a content child of TodoAppComponent. We can access it in the following way:

Now my question here is . why didn't we just used ViewChild in todo-app component for accessing app-fotter inteance?
`

Comment: Check this link, https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Answer (score 0):

so i know we use content-child when there's a content projection . 
now when i know in my todo-app component  we are projecting footer-component.
Then why not just use viewChild inside todo-app component?

It's because 'ViewChild refer to the child element present inisde the component template ref itself '  therefore since the app-footer / footer component isn't actualy inside its template but was actually projected.
Just want to clear up the concept.